# Is loop 'for element in list_[a:b]' using unused copy optimized by interpreters?

Tags: python, loops, copy, cpython

Is this :

```
for element in list_[a:b]:
```

translated during interpretation (CPython) to be equivalent to :

```
for i in range(a, b):
    element = list_[i]
```

or is the copy

```
list_[a:b]
```

really performed ?

Comment: The compiler has no way to know whether `list_` is actually a `list` or a custom object, hence it **cannot** optimize that operation away.

Comment: `list_[a:b]` gets evaluated. So yes, a new copy is made. Perhaps you want `itertools.islice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copy is really performed. The interpreter has no way of knowing what kind of object `list_` is at runtime and what you will do with it (maybe you'll start editing the original `list_`).
If you want to not produce the copy, use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
import itertools

def f(list_, a, b):
    for element in itertools.islice(list_, a, b):
        element
```

---

You can look at the `islice` documentation I linked for the full (python translated) implementation but this is a simplified version:

```
def islice(itr, start, stop):
    for index, element in enumerate(itr):
         if index == stop:
              break
         if start <= index:
              yield element
```

Comment: ok thanks guys (answer and comments) ... A last clarification : `itertools.islice` use is equivalent to loop in a range and then access by index ?

Comment: @E.B. see my edited answer. `islice` works on any iterable, even those that don't have index access (like generators). However, it is functionally equivalent to how you described when used on lists.